# C#: Call Object of Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, object, webforms

I'm using Entity Framework with webforms, I built a class like this:

```
public class ConferenceAction : IDisposable
{
    private PromotionsEntities db = new Models.PromotionsEntities();

    public void add (string name, string last Name)
    { 
        using ( PromotionsEntities db = new Models.PromotionsEntities())
        {
              //..... add code; 
        } 
    }

    public void delete(int id) 
    {
        var delterow = db.confrences.Find(id); 
        //delete code;  
    }
}
```

My question is: which best to way to work with Entities

Second question:  Which best way to use object for best performance?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The code is unreadable at a glance like that. Someone else has done it for you, but you should take care to do it yourself in future.

Comment: What is your question? It is nearly not understandable what you are asking